# Unable to access EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, autoscaling, elastic-load-balancer

I am using AWS and i created Auto scaling launch configuration using shell Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -L https://us-west-2-aws-training.s3.amazonaws.com/awsu-spl/spl03-working-elb/static/bootstrap-elb.sh | sh
```

After creating this and the load balancer, two instances were created. I then copied the DNS Name and pasted it in browser, but it says:

```
This site can’t be reached

internal-elb-asg-167368762.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com took too long to respond.
Go to http://amazonaws.com/
Search Google for internal elb asg 167368762 east amazonaws
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Comment: Have you configured a health check for the load balancer and are the instances status show as "In Service" in the load balancer ?

Comment: Internal Elb's are not accessible to internet.

Comment: Please confirm that the *very first* line of the User Data starts with `#!`. It must *not* have any spaces or blank lines before these characters, otherwise the script will not execute at startup.

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT

I followed your steps and it failed.

You have to change this part of the User Data:

```
#!/bin/sh curl -L https://us-west-2-aws-training.s3.amazonaws.com/awsu-spl/spl03-working-elb/static/bootstrap-elb.sh | sh
```

With this:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -L https://us-west-2-aws-training.s3.amazonaws.com/awsu-spl/spl03-working-elb/static/bootstrap-elb.sh | sh
```

> Edit: As @john-rotenstein mentioned is not necessary to use sudo.

Also, check this:

- You have the correct security groups on EC2 and with your ELB.
- Check if you are listening to the port 80 in you ELB.
- The port 80 must be opened in your EC2 security group to your ELB security group and the port 80 must be opened worldwide (0.0.0.0) in your ELB security group.

Finally, are you sure that you are not using an internal load balancer right?

Hope it helps you.

Comment: User Data executes as the Root user when the instance starts. Therefore, `sudo` is not required. (However, if you are running the script manually as `ec2-user`, you will need to use `sudo`.)

Comment: When I checked the logs (web console) it was executed as ec2-user and not as root

Comment: [Running Commands on Your Linux Instance at Launch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html): "Scripts entered as user data are executed as the root user, so do not use the sudo command in the script."

Comment: You are right, my bad. The user-data that I was testing was wrong. And it doesn't need sudo.